# PHP: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() and Crypto Security vs Extreme Randomness

Tags: php, cryptography, openssl

Doing some research into openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()  in PHP and I noticed that in the implementation of the of the openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()function in PHP's source. OpenSSL's **RAND_pseudo_bytes** function is used to generate the return value as opposed to **RAND_bytes** also available in OpenSSL.

OpenSSL's documentation of these two functions are as follows:

> **RAND_pseudo_bytes()** puts num pseudo-random bytes into buf. 
>   Pseudo-random byte sequences generated by RAND_pseudo_bytes() will be
>   unique if they are of sufficient length, but are not necessarily
>   unpredictable. They can be used for non-cryptographic purposes and for
>   certain purposes in cryptographic protocols, but usually not for key
>   generation etc.
>
> **RAND_bytes()** puts num cryptographically strong pseudo-random bytes
>   into buf. An error occurs if the PRNG has not been seeded with enough
>   randomness to ensure an unpredictable byte sequence.

I guess my question is why wasn't RAND_bytes used or  why isn't there also a openssl_rand_bytes() function in PHP if it is, according to OpenSSL, more random.

Just curious. Was it a speed concern? Not reliable enough? Or was the PRNG the issue (ie: to hard to implement when the pseudo works fine for most purposes) ?

Thanks

Comment: Because PHP devs didn't know what they're doing.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That may be true, but as PRNG commonly is a synonym for DRNG, I wonder if the same thing is not also true for OpenSSL. With this kind of naming you can wait for this kind of mistake to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice was probably made based on practicality rather than the soundness of the crypto. If `RAND_bytes()` is used, the function may fail due to insufficient randomness being available. The author of the PHP code no doubt wanted to avoid the PHP function failing.

I notice though that the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` function does have an optional `crypto_strong` parameter, which lets the caller know whether the returned bytes really were cryptographically strong, in the opinion of OpenSSL.

As an aside, it is possible to configure OpenSSL with external engines and some of them (such as CHIL) use a hardware-based random source for both `RAND_pseudo_bytes()` and `RAND_bytes()` if that's what you need.

Also, on Windows the PHP code is using [`CryptGenRandom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).