# Is openssl_random_pseudo_bytes truly random?

Tags: php, random, cryptography

I'm wondering about why this function has an "pseudo" on it's name. Can I trust that those bytes are really random? I didn't find any explanation about this in php's manual.

```
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to have true randomness. Even hardware randomness generators are not perfect.

Comment: Have a look at [Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generators](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generators), then read [the manual page of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](//php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

Comment: This is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28113145/4486839).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of interpretation of the word "Pseudo" in Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG). It can either mean that the results may not be fully random. It may also mean that the random number generator itself is *deterministic*. This is what meant by pseudo in the OpenSSL sense.

Good Deterministic Random Bit Generators (DRBG) - just another term for PRNG - have a very high cycle time. That means that the output should be indistinguishable from random as long as there is enough entropy in the given seed data - it will take forever before it starts to repeat itself. Most DRBG's of libraries / systems are seeded when they are initialized, again this is true for the OpenSSL one as well.

Often "true random" is meant for random values directly retrieved from sources of entropy. Quite often these sources do provide enough entropy, but that does not necessarily mean that the entropy is well distributed. Hence it is often better and faster to use the entropy of the true random source to seed a DRBG.

Now the random sources are often only available to the operating system (as they are often linked to low level I/O operations). Hence the random seed is first used for random pools in the OS (e.g. `/dev/random`) which can in turn be used for seeding the DRBG's. These pools are often already whitened to create a better distribution.

So you would get: entropy -> os entropy pool -> openssl random_pseudo_bytes -> PHP wrapper -> your application.

When on embedded systems you may want to heed the following warning:

> It also indicates if a cryptographically strong algorithm was used to produce the pseudo-random bytes, and does this via the optional `crypto_strong` parameter. It's rare for this to be `FALSE`, but some systems may be broken or old.

Otherwise it is probably the most reliable source for random numbers.